# Tomcat deployment resource not found

Tags: java, web-applications, deployment, tomcat7

I just deployed a web application to my server using tomcat manager.

When I'm running the web app locally I can get:
http://localhost:8080/CookEatWebApp/resources/ingredient SUCCESSFULLY

However, after deployment I get:
http://162.253.126.28/CookEatWebApp/resources/ingredient NOT FOUND

http://162.253.126.28/CookEatWebApp - this is working and showing the index.jsp page successfully.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this was to redeploy the latest code which contained the required controller